# Finding f intervals in trig function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I find the intervals in which f decreases and decreases in the following function.

$f(x)=2x-\cos(x)$ defined on $[0,2 \pi$]

taking the derivative I have $2+sin(x)=0$

the $sin(x)=-2$ but I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivation is correct!

$\sin(x) \neq 2$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. *There are no zeros*.

But we can still proceed! Recall: $$\sin(x) \leq |1|\quad\text{for all}\;\;x \in \mathbb{R}. \quad\text{I.e., }\;-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$$

So your derivative will evaluate to between $2 - (-1) = 3$ and $2 - 1 = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. That is, for all real $x$, $$f'(x) \in [1, 3] > 0$$

Hence, the derivative is always positive, hence the *function* $f(x)$ is always increasing.

Here's visual confirmation, compliments of [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29=2x-%5Ccos%28x%29):

[image]

Comment: Yes it is always increasing so I would write f increases on (-infinity,infinity)

Comment: Exactly, that's correct!

Comment: I see it makes sense thanks.